# Bootstrap Select - Hide optgroup and border if does not have any searchable content inside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using Bootstrap Selectbox which has live search as well...

While searching, if there is no results found in  tag, relevant  also should hide.

Please help me out...

---

> **Scenario with HTML**

---

I have a selectbox like below:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <optgroup label="Option Group 1">
      <option selected>a</option>
      <option>b</option>
      <option>c</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Option Group 2">
      <option>d</option>
      <option>e</option>
      <option>f</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

When I try to search for "**e**" it should hide first option group.

> **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if ($(".selectpicker li").hasClass("hide")) {
        $(this).prev(".dropdown-header").hide();
     }     
 });
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6cjy3rn6/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking for same solution using yii2 for bootstrap-select

Ok here the good news that with new version of bootstrap-select.js 1.11.2 they have resolved the problem of hiding empty optgroup.

so enjoy by download new version and use it.

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 3):

I am using bootstrap-select.js 1.11.2 and I have done following to hide options and optgroup.

In JQuery, you need to disabled options under a optgroup.

```
$("optgroup[label='optgroup_label']").children().prop('disabled', true);
```

Ref: [Selectpicker example to disable](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh)

In HTML, you need to add **data-hide-disabled:"true"** in **select** tag:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple title="..." data-size="7" data-live-search="true" data-selected-text-format="count" data-hide-disabled="true">
```

Ref: [Selectpicker Core options](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/#core-options)

Comment: Your reference links are broken.

Comment: Links are okay now.